# Using regular expressions to get each item in a list

Tags: regex, qregexp

How can I use QRegExps to find each item in a list? What I am trying to do is to get each team in a list. They must be separated by a comma or a comma and space. For example, I want to get each team in this list:

```
    Patriots, Celtics, Red Sox
```

My initial regular expression was:

```
    [^, ]+
```

There is a problem with this because teams are allowed to have space characters in them, such as the Red Sox. Another one I tried was this:

```
    [^,] +
```

But that caused problems because it grabbed the space after the comma, and appended it to the beginning of the name of the following item in the list.

Any solutions?

Comment: Regular expressions *can* do this job, but I think you'll find that [`split()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#split) handles it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = str.split(QRegExp(",\\s+"));
```

Or, when whitespaces are optional:

```
list = str.split(QRegExp(",\\s*"));
```

Comment: It sounds to me like the whitespace is optional, which means you want `\s*`, not `\s+`.